# Declaring class methods in a function and accessing its values from another function

Tags: python, class

I've never really used classes before, I just simply went the easy way (global variables), and now I would like to make my code right to avoid future complications.

This is my code:

```
from dearpygui.core import *

class Engine:
    def __init__(self,serial,type,profile):
        self.serial = serial
        self.type = type
        self.profile = profile

def apply_selected_file():

res = []
html_name= "example.html"
path= "C:/"

#Function that reads data from a file and saves selected data in a list
res = html_imp(path + '/' + html_name)

#I would like to remove the code below and use a class for each file instead

setvalue(sn1,es[0]) #shows a label with this value
setvalue(type1,res[1]) #shows a label with this value
setvalue(profile1,res[2]) #shows a label with this value

return res

def button():

#This was my initial idea but it doesn't seem to work.

# res = apply_selected_file()
# E = Engine(res[0],res[1],res[2])
```

I have in mind reading multiple HTML files so using a class would be much easier than declaring variables for each file:

1- Use apply_selected_file to read a file and assign values (s/n,type,profile) to a new class (E1,E2,E3,...,E20,...)

2- Use another function button() to access those stored class values.

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) Explain what you want in more detail (edit the question).

Comment: @MichaelButscher done

Comment: Where is `set_value` defined and what does it do?

Comment: @Samwise set_value is a built-in function from dearpygui, it basically just shows a label in the GUI, but that is irrelevant to the class, as only the "res" list is used.